# Quickblox, Video chat for PC/Mac, options other than WebRTC

Tags: quickblox, opentok, videochat

Are there options to make a video chat app for PC/mac using quickblox but not WebRTC?
The business case is to provide video chat facility from iPhone/iPad with a user on pc/Mac.
We do not want to use WebRTC..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i went ahead and did a POC to test the capabilities of quickblox, well bluntly put, it does not support native ios app to call a web based app.
However i then explored OpenTok which actually works cross platform, atleast from iOS to web.
My problem solved.